# Change outcome of defined function in another defined function?

Tags: python, list, function

is it possible to change the output of a defined function when another defined function triggers a change of the first function?

For example I have a function which contains a list of integers and if the second function triggers a defined event, the list of integers should be changed.

Has anyone found a solution?

Like this:

```py
def A(x)
    list(integers)
```

and if in def B a event occurs this list should be an empty list.

Is this possible?

Comment: that list will get garbage collected and it will only exist for a short period of time when you call `A`, you are better of changing some global variable instead or use OOP and modify some attribute instead

Comment: The list in A is not really a fix list, it depends on the input. The list contains missing values and if those missing values are fixed in B, the list should be cleared. That is my problem

Comment: You mean that the second function should, as a side effect, change the output of a previously called function? If the second function contains a reference to the output of the first function, and that output is mutable, then you could do something like that. On the other hand, it is typically bad design to have functions work by side effect. If you want more detailed help, you need to edit your question so that it is less vague.